# What does the Torah mean when it restricts homosexual relations?

Tags: halacha, torah-study, sexuality, non-rabbinic-judaism, homosexuality

A relative of mine, who happens to be gay, asked me if Oral sex is sanctioned under the scope of the restrictions on homosexual relations. If I remember correctly, the Torah forbids, for males, the act of "lying" with mankind. That is not the same as Oral sex, which isn't technically "lying" as there is no penetration. Curious to know the halachic standard/approach.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100871/what-is-the-jewish-law-on-homosexual-acts-not-explicitly-prohibited-in-the-torah?rq=1